# How to get HTML elements from a file using PHP

Tags: php, html, file

Currently I am using file_get_contents to get contents of an HTML page I have.

```
    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
    echo "file exists!";
    $current = file_get_contents("./docs/page1.html");
    echo $current;
} else {
    echo "file doesn't exist";
    file_put_content($fileName, "testing creating a new page"); 
}
```

when the HTML file exists, I store the content using file_get_contents in variable $current and then echo current. However, nothing displays. Just a black page (which I'm guessing is the css in the html page)

If I can't spit out the page, is there a way to extract each element of the html page (divs, etc)?

Comment: Why are you checking if `$fileName` exists, and then getting `./docs/page1.html`? Is that the same file?

Comment: Yes, use an HTML parser

Comment: Have you considered using the `include` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file_put_content** is not a function. Try **file_put_contents**

Also look at the changes i did to your script. It will give you information if the file can be created/read or not.

```
<?php 
    $fileName = './docs/page1.html';
    if($current = file_get_contents($fileName)){
        echo "file exists!";
        echo $current;
    } else {
        echo "file doesn't exist";
        if (file_put_contents($fileName, "testing creating a new page")){
            echo 'created a new file!';
        } else {
            echo 'Error, couldnt create file! Maybe I dont have write permissions?';
        }
    }
?>
```

I tested this script, and it works unless **it doesnt have file permissions**. So make sure you set file permissions on the folder containing the file as well.

Comment: you're right. it seems like it doesn't have the permissions. however, i changed the permissions. my files are being pushed to my web server. is it enough that i change the permission locally?

Comment: When you change file permissions locally they will get lost in the transfer. You need to set the permissions again on the webserver.

Comment: also, the issue of echo-ing $current still persists...the content of that file are not displayed there is only a black page (from the css of the html page im guessing)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is the text on the page also black like on the background?

Comment: not a stupid question. In any case, i highlighted the page anyway and the only text on their is the php echo messages

Comment: Have you opened the actual file and looked if something was inside?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the page, but are probably lacking content on the page that uses relative paths, such as CSS and images.

If you wish to only use part of the page, I suggest looking into DOMDocument.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php